# «Я… Я должен что-то сделать...» – строчная или заглавная буква?

Tags: многоточие

Как действовать в высказываниях, где произносится одно слово, а потом, после многоточия, повторяется? Второе слово должно быть с большой буквы или малой?

И ещё почти такой же вопрос. Есть, например, такое предложение: «Хм... Думаю, нет». Если есть междометие (или вводное слово), после которого сразу идёт многоточие, то следующая часть пишется с большой или маленькой буквы?

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше со строчной, но можно и с прописной, если это начало предложения.

> «Хм... Думаю, нет». Если есть междометие (или вводное слово), после
> которого сразу идёт многоточие, то следующая часть пишется с большой
> или маленькой буквы?

Да всё равно же! Если пауза, выраженная отточием, затянулась, следующую прописную объясним как начало нового предложения. Сократим паузу - строчная.

Прописная нужна, если отточие перебивает мысль, если не читается как продолжение.

*Видимо... Ох, нет, этого я вам не посоветую.*

Всё.